# WHERE Clause syntax

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

What's up with my sysntax, I can't get it right. Is there a better way?

```
<?
            $uid = $_GET["uid"];
            $month= $_GET["month"];
            $year = $_GET["year"];
            $query = "SELECT taskname,uid,month,year, SUM(tasktime) FROM tictoc WHERE uid = $uid, month = $month, year = $year GROUP BY taskname"; 

            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

            // Print out result
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<br />";
                echo "Total ". $row['taskname']. " = <strong>". $row['SUM(tasktime)']."</strong>";
                echo "<br />";
            }
            ?>
```

Error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' month = 'Aug', year = '2012' GROUP BY taskname' at line 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `AND`, not a comma, like this:

```
select taskname, uid, month, year, SUM(tasktime)
from tictoc
where uid = $uid
    and month = $month
    and year = $year
group by taskname
```

Also, note the line:

```
echo "Total ". $row['taskname']. " = <strong>". $row['SUM(tasktime)']."</strong>";
```

will not work. You need to alias the sum in your query and reference that alias, like this:

```
SELECT taskname,uid,month,year, SUM(tasktime) as SumTaskTime
```

and then do:

```
echo "Total ". $row['taskname']. " = <strong>". $row['SumTaskTime)']."</strong>";
```

Comment: OK that got rid of that error, but now it says Unknown column Aug' in 'where clause'

Comment: Thanks, but now i'm still getting error: Unknown column 'Aug' in 'where clause'

Comment: Aug is supposed to be the month

Comment: @Hector, you may need quotes around the values if they are varchar or similar. What are your data types?

Answer (score 1):

To complement the previous answer, check that the parameters are not arriving empty.  For example:

```
 $uid = $_GET["uid"] = $_GET["uid"] == "" ? 0 : $_GET["uid"];
 $month = $_GET["month"] = $_GET["month"] == "" ? 0 : $_GET["month"];
 $year = $_GET["year"] = $_GET["year"] == "" ? 0 : $_GET["year"];
```

Or choose your checking strategy.

The reason is if they are arriving empty and you don't validate it, you will build your SQL statement incorrectly and you will have the error you are reporting.